# How Can I Run FLOAT64 Values In A Query using Python BigQuery?

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a Flask server that takes in arguments and then uses those arguments to run this query here:

```
runQuery = f"UPDATE `mytable` SET start_date='{inf['start_date']}', end_date='{inf['end_date']}', store_ids='{inf['store_ids']}', salary='{float(inf['salary'])}' WHERE row_id = '{row_id}'"

job = client.query(runQuery)
```

Where SALARY is a float number like "50000.0" (it would be inputted as a string, hence why I tried to convert it to a FLOAT)

The problem is, BigQuery does not like it. I keep getting this error

```
Value of type STRING cannot be assigned to salary, which has type FLOAT64
```

Comment: just remove single quotes?! so use `salary={float(inf['salary'])}`

Comment: Thank you @MikhailBerlyant! How do I upvote your comment?

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant, can you post your comment as an answer so that the community can easily find the answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting @MikhailBerlyant's answer in the comment section as a Community wiki answer:

Just remove single quotes. Use `salary={float(inf['salary'])}`